# Нужно ли названия символов заключать в кавычки?

Tags: значение-слов, прописная-строчная, кавычки, знак

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли названия символов заключать в кавычки и нужны ли прописные буквы? А в сочетании с родовым словом? Каково вообще правило на эти случаи?

*Увидел "инь-ян", "уроборос" и "волчий крюк"; увидел символы "инь-ян", "уроборос" и "волчий крюк"...*